# Android how to change value of a Key/Value Pair inside JSONObject

Tags: android, json

Hi i want to change/alter value of a string inside a json object which inside a JSONArray and which is from a file stored in internal storage.

My initial thoughts are to convert the object to a string do a find a replace and convert back to `JSONObject` search the `JSONArray` for the JSONObject remove the old one and put the new one in. Then save the array as a .JSON File to internal storage (will this replace the file thats already there or will it create another file with the same name?).

This is my initial thoughts on how to do this but is this the correct way or is there easier more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to retrieve the required JSON Object form the JSON Array.

You can update the key-value pair of your JSON Object directly by using

**`mJsonObj.put("<key>", <value>)`**.

Comment: will this replace the key value pair that already exists in the JSON Object or will it simply just add another key Value pair into it. i need to replace the one thats there rather than add another

Comment: It will replace, because you are not going to create a new JSON Object. You need to get the reference to the existing JSON Object present in the array, by doing something like `mJsonObj = mJsonArray.get("JsonObject")`.

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat nice and simple. does the same apply for jsonArrays if i put that object in will it replace it

Comment: Glad to be of help! :) And well, yes, the same applies for everything, as long as you are taking the reference to the existing object and not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the library you are using for parsing JSON. Some do allow code like `jsonOArray.get("jsonObject").put("key", "val");`

Some require to obtain the object first then do something like

```
JsonObj = jsonArray.get("jsonObject"); jsonObj.putVal("key", "val");
```

Which library do you use for processing json?

Comment: im not sure i think its JSON.org

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_id", cus_id));
```

getting data in this:

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
 JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
cus_points = json_data.getString("cus_points");
```